# A problem in setting network option in Pyvis

Tags: python, json, pyvis

I think I need some help......
I'm using Pyvis to visualize a social network graph, and I want to set some options for the network.
trying to set some

```
# Visualization
net = Network(height='1000px',width='80%',bgcolor='#222222',filter_menu=True,select_menu=True, notebook=True,cdn_resources='remote',font_color="white") # define the network class
net.set_options('''
const options = {
  "nodes": {
    "borderWidth": null,
    "borderWidthSelected": null,
    "opacity": null,
    "size": null
  },
  "edges": {
    "arrows": {
      "to": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "inherit": true
    },
    "selfReferenceSize": null,
    "selfReference": {
      "angle": 0.7853981633974483
    },
    "smooth": {
      "forceDirection": "none"
    }
  },
  "physics": {
    "barnesHut": {
      "gravitationalConstant": -80000,
      "springLength": 250,
      "springConstant": 0.001
    },
    "minVelocity": 0.75
  }
}''')

net.barnes_hut()
# Add center nodes
net.add_nodes(selected_nodes[number[0]:number[1]],title = ['1' for i in range(number[0],number[1])],\
              color = ['#FFA500' for i in range(number[0],number[1])],\
            label = [nodes[selected_nodes[i]] for i in range(number[0],number[1])],size = [degrees[selected_nodes[i]] for i in range(number[0], number[1])])

# Add one hop neighbors
net.add_nodes(selected_nodes[number[1]:number[2]],title = ['2' for i in range(number[1],number[2])],\
              color = ['#FFFF00' for i in range(number[1],number[2])],\
             label = [nodes[selected_nodes[i]] for i in range(number[1],number[2])],size = [degrees[selected_nodes[i]] for i in range(number[1], number[2])])
net.add_edges(selected_edges[number[1]-number[1]:number[2]-number[1]])

# Add two hop neighbors
net.add_nodes(selected_nodes[number[2]:number[3]],title = ['3' for i in range(number[2],number[3])],\
              color = ['#00FFFF' for i in range(number[2],number[3])],\
              label = [nodes[selected_nodes[i]] for i in range(number[2],number[3])],size = [degrees[selected_nodes[i]] for i in range(number[2], number[3])])
net.add_edges(selected_edges[number[2]-number[1]:number[3]-number[1]])

# Add complement Edges
net.add_edges(edges_complement)

# Display
net.toggle_physics(True)
net.show_buttons(filter_=['nodes','edges','physics'])
net.show('test.html')
```

However, when I run the code, I come through an Attribute error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Study\Courses\2023Fall\Social Network Mining\FinaL_PJ_code\GCN\pygcn\visualization.py", line 137, in 
net.barnes_hut()
File "D:\Study\Courses\2023Fall\Social Network Mining\FinaL_PJ_code\GCN\venv\lib\site-packages\pyvis\network.py", line 782, in barnes_hut
self.options.physics.use_barnes_hut(locals())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'physics'

I think that self.option should be an 'Option' object, rather than a 'dict', but how can I fix it ?

I've tried to look through the source code and figure out how to turn a 'dict' object to an 'Option' object, but failed.
That's my first question in Stack Overflow, and I'm looking forward timely helps. Thank you very much.